# Retrieve data using SqlQuery<T> in Entity Framework with SQL Server not working

Tags: ef-core-7.0

I try to access some columns of the one table using `SqlQuery` in the Entity Framework.

Here is my code:

```
public class CreatedByAuditTrial
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

}

var usermstHsCreateDetail = db.Database.SqlQuery<CreatedByAuditTrial>($"Select ID,CreatedBy,CreatedOn   from USERMST");
```

But I got an error :

> The element type 'UserManagement.ViewModel.CreatedByAuditTrial' used in 'SqlQuery' method is not natively supported by your database provider. Either use a supported element type, or use ModelConfigurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping to define a mapping for your type.

I found that the column property and name should be the same (ID is int field), but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: db.Database.SqlQuery<int>($"Select ID from USERMST") - try to use int

Comment: but there are some other columns like FirstName as string and LastName as string

Comment: @Roank1112 post the actual code then, and add the correct tags. This has nothing to do with either SQL Server or ASP.NET Core. This is an EF or EF Core issue. Which one are you using, which version? [SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types) in EF Core 7 and later only maps *scalar* types, not objects. You can use `SqlQuery<int>` but not `SqlQuery<MyObject>`. EF Classic 6.2 had a SqlQuery that could map to complex non-entity types

Comment: What does your DbContext and entities look like? Why not use `Select` to map an entity to a ViewModel?

Comment: because I want to use SQL statements with multiple case statements and other complex SQL query.

Comment: I have updated my question with require entity and SqlQuery

Comment: try to use nullable datatypes.. if your query allow to return null values in some columns. for example  DateTime? CreatedOn. Also check that column names will matched with properties.

Comment: it's not working with SqlQuery<Object>.

Comment: .Net FrameworkCore 7.0.2

Comment: There's no `.Net FrameworkCore 7.0.2`. You may be referring to .NET (Core) 7. The `Core` part was removed in .NET 5 for marketing reasons

Comment: As for `with multiple case statements and other complex SQL query` don 't use EF Core then. EF Core is an ORM, not a database driver or data access library. It's job is to Map Relational structures to Objects and give the impression of working with objects instead of tables. The object mapping information is stored in DbSet. If you want to execute raw queries, use ADO.NET directly

Comment: `multiple case statements` that's quite often a problem in SQL, not just ORMs, because inefficient CASE clauses can prevent the database from using indexes. When using LINQ you can eliminate the need for `CASE` by chaining just the calls you need in each case, or using different expressions in `Select` or `Where`

Comment: You can see the tutorial [link](https://youtu.be/BxMXBJYLdGI?si=yVDLbfqgtxNHCS5z?&=12m) for non entity type data retrieval.

Comment: I am doing the same But it not work for me.